# Get window xid from handle for drawing GStreamer video in Python

Tags: python, gstreamer, electron

I am working on porting a Linux desktop app to an [Emberjs](http://emberjs.com/) on [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) application to allow for a more customized user interface.  While most of the controls are a good fit for HTML and CSS, I need to be able to draw around a dozen video displays inside the Electron window, and I'm concerned that doing this via a pile of RTSP streams would be significant overhead.

The video is available from GStreamer pipelines that I built in Python, and normally I would draw on an existing GTK application using something like the following:

```
pipeline.add(src, sink)
src.link(sink)

window = Gtk.Window()
window.connect("delete-event", window_closed, pipeline)
window.set_default_size (1280, 720)
window.set_title ("Hello OpenGL Sink!")

drawing_area = Gtk.DrawingArea()
drawing_area.set_double_buffered (True)
window.add (drawing_area)

window.show_all()
window.realize()

xid = drawing_area.get_window().get_xid()
sink.set_window_handle (xid)
```

The `gtk.DrawingArea` has a `get_window()` method that can be used to find the window and xid to draw on.  Electron's BrowserWindow has a [function to get the Window handle](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/#wingetnativewindowhandle).  However, this returns an unsigned long as an 8 byte [Node.js buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html).

Is there a way in python to turn this Window handle into a Window object to find the xid?  Is there a way to look up the xid based on the unsigned long handle?

Answer (score 1):

The window handle *is* the XID. Call `.readUInt32LE()` to convert the buffer to an integer.

Comment: That's what I figured.  It turns out that even with this handle, there is an issue drawing onto it because Electron goes through the GPU, and can't be drawn on in the same fashion as, say, a GTK DrawingArea.